# Copying Cells Via Loop-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to run this loop I get an Error: Object Required in the `Cell.Value.Copy` line. What do I need to do to fix this error?

```
Sub Findings()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Cell As Object
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C74")
For Each Cell In Rng
  If (Cell.Value <> "") Then
    Cell.Value.Copy
  End If
Next Cell

If IsEmpty(Range("C85").Value) = True Then
  Range("C85").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("C86").Value) = True Then
  Range("C86").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("C87").Value) = True Then
  Range("C87").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use `Cell.Copy`.

Comment: The loop that you have which begins `For Each Cell In Rng` is a bit pointless since subsequent passes through the loop overwrite the value in the clipboard from earlier passes through the loop. In VBA there is almost never a good reason to use copy/paste to transfer values -- just directly assign to the `.Value` of the target ranges.

Comment: @gg315 have you tried the code in my answer below ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I have, thank you! The SpecialCells tip was really useful--really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy only cells with values (without formulas that are returning empty values), you can use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to set the range.

See my code below:

```
Sub Findings()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Rng As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' set "Rng" only to cells inside the range with values inside them
    Set Rng = .Range("C5:C74").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Rng.Copy

    If IsEmpty(.Range("C85").Value) Then
        .Range("C85").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ElseIf IsEmpty(.Range("C86").Value) Then
        .Range("C86").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ElseIf IsEmpty(.Range("C87").Value) Then
        .Range("C87").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

End With    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```